# HTML 5 Video Player within a submission Form is redirected to the post action script after clicking the play button

Tags: forms, html5-video

I meet a problem with HTML 5 Video Player, I embed the player inside a submission form, but when I click the the play button, it play the video for a second and then the whole page is redirected to the post action script. for example:

```
<form  method = "post" action="form_submision.php">
  
  <button type="submit" id="submit1"></button>
  <button type="submit" id="submit2"></button>

  <table>
    <tr>
   <td>
   
   <video id="video1" width="279" height="237" poster="video1.jpg" src="video1.mp4"    preload="meta"></video>

  </td>
  </tr>

  </table>

  </form>
```

I expect to play the video while the form is not submitted (the whole page is not redirected to the post action script, it is just standing there).

Comment: Double check what you posted. Your code doesn't work in Chrome. What happens if you put your video `src` inside an actual `<source>` tag? What happens if you have a blank action like `action=" "`? Do any of those help the video to work without a re-direct? If not then you need to **create testable code** (starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and ends with a `</html>` like in [this example code](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)). Provide a real link to a PHP file if it is important to test the submission part also

Comment: PS: After I put a `<source>` tag in your code, I could see and play my video file link but there was no automatic re-direct. Maybe Chrome doesn't re-direct (it always allows playback inside form?) or may Chrome did not redirect because the PHP file did not exist to accept such a command.

Comment: Thank you all, this problem has been solved, it is caused by the video play related js script which shall be added at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved. You can make an Answer in the big box below if you think your solution will help others using video inside forms. Not clear if you mean the problem was caused by JS code that you did not show in your posted question? Or you mean you had to actually add new JS code to tell the video to play as a solution? No pressure to share answer (your comment might be enough to help someone else).